# How To Install / Get QuickFIX Libraries

Tags: .net, vb.net, libraries, quickfix, installation

I am creating an application using QuickFIX/N, since I am coding inside of VB.NET. Now, this has always been my issue for the longest time, and the online documentation is shit - or just overly confusing in my opinion.

After I have both QuickFIX and QuickFIX/N how do I go about running the .bat or .jar files in order to grab the libraries needed for my application to work?

Comment: Please, could you be more specific?

Comment: http://www.quickfixengine.org/ - QuickFIX is a compilation of libraries that works with the FIX protocol, usually seen in the trading industry. I am trying to install the QuickFIX/N (noted on that website) yet have no idea how to use the .dll and pull in the libraries for me to use them within my application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, download the latest version here: http://www.quickfixn.org/download

Unzip the downloaded file in a folder of your choice, then please read the file **README.md**

Here: http://www.quickfixn.org/tutorial/creating-an-application you can find a simple example to create your first application.

Comment: I realized my mistake was a simple one - I did that initially though I am working in Visual Studio (using VB.NET to work with Excel) and I never made a "reference" to the file that is in the bin folder.